# Are all horses in Corona intelligent?

Tags: disney, tangled

In Tangled (2010), the horse Maximus displays clear signs of intelligence. Although he does not speak (in any language that humans can understand), he takes and executes complex orders from humans, works as part of a team, formulates plans, and effectively utilizes melee weapons.

Are all horses in the universe of Tangled similarly intelligent as Maximus, or is Maximus special in some way?

- Are all horses in Corona intelligent?
- Is Maximus unique?
- Is Corona inhabited by both intelligent and non-intelligent horses, with Maximus hailing from the first population?

Comment: in Cinderella (1950), the mice display clear signs of intelligence, including speech.  Are mice in France intelligent?

Comment: Talking or intelligent animals are often inserted into Disney princess movies as a form of comedic or wholesome relief. I don't think their presence is intended to be taken seriously.

Comment: HNQ trolling with the title?

Comment: @Adamant no, just a coincidence. I was going to ask the question before I remembered the kingdom's name.

Comment: I hear Minimus isn't so bright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He’s not unique; the series brings us Axel, a horse of similar intelligence. [IMDb](https://imdb.com/title/tt7521200/) describes the episode he is in:

> A new crime-fighting horse arrives in Corona, and Maximus has found a best buddy. But it doesn't take long for Max to realize his new stable-mate didn't come to town to make nice.

Here is the start of the episode:

Based off everyone’s reactions, horses like these are not uncommon; it’s possible that every horse is intelligent.

Comment: "Hero" horses (e.g. those used and extensively seen on screen like Fidella) seem to be smarter than IRL horses. Other horses (those used by the guards) seem to have the same intelligence as IRL horses.... unless they're being interacted with by a main character or guest star